# Replacing outer double quotes using gsub and regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm not sure this is even the right way to go about this but I'm two days into regex.  Using the pattern, either in Rubular, or with Ruby match or scan, I see the right characters are getting matched.  Problem is I can't figure out why
the outer double quotes are not being replaced.

```
def fields(fos)
  fos.gsub(/("*)(\W+)/, "', '")
end

p fields("Pete,201,Student")
p fields("Pete \t 201    ,  TA")
p fields("Pete \t 201")
```

supposed to return this:

```
# -> ['Pete', '201', 'Student'] 
# -> ['Pete', '201', 'TA']
# -> ['Pete', '201']
```

instead I'm getting this -

```
"Pete', '201', 'Student"
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

The *outer double quotes* are just used by ruby to represent a *String* object, so you won't be able to replace them (and won't need to).

But it seems that you are trying to set an array (e.g. `['Pete', '201', 'Student']` is an array of three strings) so you could use `split`, like this:

```
def fields(fos)
  fos.split(/[,|\s]+/)
end

p fields("Pete,201,Student")
# ["Pete", "201", "Student"]

p fields("Pete \t 201    ,  TA")
# ["Pete", "201", "TA"]

p fields("Pete \t 201")
# ["Pete", "201"]
```

Comment: thanks!, @Gerry The output is similar as when I use str#scan.  I'm still left with double quotes. Maybe I just need to change some things in the pattern to put single quotes around the words. I figured the double quotes around the outer string was Ruby.

Comment: @stuartambient You won't be able to replace the double quotes that represent the string, if that is what are you after. Could you be more specific about what are you trying to achieve? I think i am not fully understanding your need.

Comment: The @Gerry input would be this (to the method) `p fields("Pete \t 201    ,  TA")`  Just poorly formatted delimeters that need to be cleaned up.
The output  should be this # ->` ['Pete', '201', 'TA'],` Basically what I have now, an array with the fields separate correctly, but single quote strings instead of double quotes.

Comment: @stuartambient The double quotes that you see in `["Pete", "201", "Student"]` are the ones used by ruby for each string in the array. If you want to add single quotes to each string then the output will be something like this: `["'Pete'", "'201'", "'Student'"]`. Maybe you want a simple string? Like this: `"['Pete', '201', 'Student']"`.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
tests=["Pete,201,Student","Pete \t 201    ,  TA","Pete \t 201"]
```

You can use a regex with `split`

```
> tests.map {|e| e.split(/[,\t ]+/) }
=> [["Pete", "201", "Student"], ["Pete", "201", "TA"], ["Pete", "201"]]
```

`split` targets the elements that separate fields, in this case runs of spaces or tabs or commas.

`split` is used to specify what is NOT you data -- in this case, you data is NOT space or tab or comma.

---

You can also use a regex to capture what you data IS -- in this case, words and numbers:

```
> s="Pete,201,Student"
> s.scan(/[a-zA-Z\d]+/)
=> ["Pete", "201", "Student"]
```

Or, for latin and non latin alphabets:

```
> s.scan(/[\p{L}\d]+/)
=> ["Pete", "201", "Student"]
```

You can also specify what your data is NOT by having a negated character class `[^]` and use that to capture things that are not a comma or space or tab:

```
> s.scan(/[^\t ,]+/)
=> ["Pete", "201", "Student"]
```

---

#### Side note:

There is ambiguity in you question (and my answer):

From `"Pete \t 201    ,  TA"` you expect three fields: `['Pete', '201', 'TA']`

What would you expect with `"A,,,,B,,,,C"`? How about `"A\tB\t\tC"`? And what about `'"A,B",C,"D,E,F"'`?

The *usual* custom with those is:

```
"A,,,,B,,,,C"      => ["A","","","B","","","C"]
"A\tB\t\tC"        => ["A","B","","C"]
'"A,B",C,"D,E,F"'  => [""A,B","C","D,E,F"]
```

If you expect the `,` and `\t` to be treated differently than runs of spaces or you expect commas inside of quoted fields to be treated differently, it rapidly becomes complicated.   And ultimately, the recommendation is to use a [CSV module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html).

But, if you are OK with ignoring quoted fields entirely like `'"A,B",C,"D,E,F"'` and want the runs of spaces to be treated differently than single commas, you can do:

```
> tests=["Pete,201,Student","Pete \t 201    ,  TA","Pete \t 201", "A,,,B,,,C"]
> tests.map {|e| e.split(/[,]|[\t ]+/) }
=> [["Pete", "201", "Student"], ["Pete", "201", "", "", "TA"], ["Pete", "201"], ["A", "", "", "B", "", "", "C"]]
```

But then that is different than you example because you are treating a comma as equivalent separator to a space or a tab. Usually, those three are treated differently.

Comment: Yeah, as I was saying below I have an array here and I'm not entirely sure I want an array.  Also, with this solution, it wasn't working sending the string in with parentheses as opposed to braces.

Comment: If you don't want an array, just use `join`: `["Pete", "201", "Student"].join(' ')` If you don't want the quotes around it, use `print`: `print ["Pete", "201", "Student"].join(' ')`

Answer (score 1):

as said above double quote is not part of your string, if your string contain dooble quote it should be like `'"Pete,201,Student"'` or `"\"Pete,201,Student\""` if you want to split string (become array `[]`) with separator non alphanumeric character use `\W`

```
def fields(fos)
  fos.split(/\W+/)
end

p fields('Pete,201,Student')
# ["Pete", "201", "Student"]

p fields("Pete \t 201    ,  TA")
# ["Pete", "201", "TA"]

p fields("Pete \n $%^^ 201")
# ["Pete", "201"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was duped! This was an exercise and the expected output printed in the problem is single quoted strings in an array.  I finally just went ahead and looked at their solution

```
def fields(fos)
  fos.split(/[ \t,]+/)
end

p fields("Pete,201,Student")
# -> ['Pete', '201', 'Student']

p fields("Pete \t 201    ,  TA")
# -> ['Pete', '201', 'TA']

p fields("Pete \t 201")
# -> ['Pete', '201']
```

Output:

```
["Pete", "201", "Student"]
["Pete", "201", "TA"]
["Pete", "201"]
```

I had this at the start, not the exact pattern but the right output.  Anyway, thanks for all the help!